# Salience value nos working correctly when mixing XLS and DRL files?

Tags: drools

I have different rules defined in DRL text files and XLS spreadsheet files. My XLS rules are executed first I am not able to understand why. The example is to manage a form with different categories and answers. The answer has a score that is used to return the user some information.

My first DRL rule is to sum all scores from all questions in a category:

```
package Form;

import ...;
rule "Sum Category Score"
salience 500
when
$form : SubmittedForm();
$cat : CategoryWithScore(score == null) from $form.categories;
$categoryScore : Number() from
    accumulate($q : Question() from $cat.getQuestions(), 
                init( int $total = 0 ),
                action( $total += $q.getAnswer().getScore(); ),
                reverse( $total -= $q.getAnswer().getScore(); ),
                result( $total ) 
            );
 then
    $cat.setScore($categoryScore);
 end
```

And with a XLS file, I define the result of a category depending on the total score.

[image: XLS definition]

As we can see, the DRL file has `salience 500` and the XLS file has `salience 250`. Then I expect that the DRL rule is executed first.

If I print the XLS in rule format, everything seems correct:

```
package ScoreClassification;
//generated from Decision Table
import ...;
    no-loop true
    salience 250
// rule values at B13, header at B8
rule "Form Score Classification_13"
       when
            $form : SubmittedForm(); $cat : CategoryWithScore($cat.getText() == 'Cat1', $cat.getScore() >= 0, $cat.getScore() < 40) from $form.getCategoriesWithScore();
    then
            $cat.setResult('Good');
 end

// rule values at B14, header at B8
...
```

I have put some simple `System.out.println` in the methods `getScore` and `setScore` of the category, to see what is happening. And I can see that `getScore` is executed first! (and has null value) and later `setScore` that assign correctly the value.

Why salience is not respected?

Comment: This behaviour is only shown when using XLS rules with DRL. The salience in the DRL is working correctly and in XLS also. Only when mixing both of them seems that XLS rules does not respect salience of DRL files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Three things.

First, you must use modify to effect a change of a fact in working memory.

```
 rule "Sum Category Score"
 ...
 then
     modify( $cat ){ setScore( $categoryScore ) }
 end
```

Otherwise, rule evaluation will never see the changed value.

**Added after OPs 1st comment**
Second, if the modification is in an object held in a collection within a fact and extracted using from, things begin to get murky. I avoid this, and recommend you to do the same. Insert the `CategoryWithScore` facts, and your problem is solved. (You may have to ascertain that the selected `CategoryWithScore` facts belong to the same `SubmittedForm`, if there is more than one form in WM at the same time.)

Third, it is a common misconception that priority (or salience) has an effect on the ordere of left hand side evaluations, and can be used to delay the evaluation of a rule where, constraint expressions may run into NPEs. It is best practice to write constraints so that null values result in a short-circuited false.

If you think that this clutters rules: yes, you are right. But even pure Java code is more robust when class members are set to some default or out-of-band value (might be -1 in your case) rather than left at null.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I have used `update($form)` without so much success (same issue). Your approach (that at the end would be `modify( $form ){ setScore( $cat, $categoryScore ) }` as $cat is not at the working memory) is correct, but does not point out the solution of the problem (I much appreciate your correction). The approach of using null values for default value of score is due to some rules has no score (i.e. Write your name), and some other questions can have a negative score. Then I realize that probably salience can be the solution for me.

Comment: Testing the `modify()` option, I have experimented an issue: `org.drools.core.reteoo.RightTuple.unlinkFromRightParent(RightTuple.java:83)` (reported here also: https://issues.jboss.org/browse/JBRULES-3687) but this is another question.

Comment: Well, having to scroll to the far right has it's drawbacks :-) Expecting changes in some subcomponent of a fact in WM to trigger re-evaluation is tricky, and that's why I always recommend to be not too niggardly w.r.t. inserts.

Comment: Adding CategoryWithScore as a fact, will launch the rule, but also nothing ensures that the categories will have the score assigned before the form rules are active. I can add some extra conditions to the form for ensuring the order, but the idea is to keep the XLS as simple as possible because probably will be maintained by a person that is not a software engineer (code in this question is simpler than the original one). In this case "salience" is comprehensible for almost anybody, other assertions are a little harder to understand.

Comment: If you have `CategoryWithScore.score` initially at -1, no XLS rule will fire until an accumulate changes this field.

Comment: Thanks @laune for your comments. With some changes my application is working. I think that these changes are more a workaround rather than a solution to the original question (do not misunderstand me, you are right that the salience must be avoided in several cases, but salience sometimes is helpful and understanding why is not working correctly would be great).

Comment: The "understanding why" is in the third part of my answer. There is no issue of "not working correctly" - it is a matter of using a feature to achieve something it never was meant to achieve - like using a hammer to turn a screw. Anyway, I've invested enough time & effort to explain things to you, but you arent' accepting my advice... Bye.